# Python - NameError: name 'q' is not defined

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm writing a script in Python that prompts you to ask a question, and analyzes the AskReddit subreddit to and gives you a response. My code is:

```
import requests
import json
import random
 
#The main function that will grab a reply
def grab_reply(question):
    #Navigate to the Search Reddit Url
    r = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/search.json?q=' + question + '&sort=relevance&t=all', headers = {'User-agent': 'Chrome'})
    
    answers = json.loads(r.text)    #Load the JSON file
    
    Children = answers["data"]["children"]
 
    ans_list= []
 
    for post in Children:
        if post["data"]["num_comments"] >= 5:   #Greater then 5 or equal  comments
            ans_list.append (post["data"]["url"])
        
    #If no results are found return "I have no idea"
    if len(ans_list) == 0:
        return "I have no idea"
    
    #Pick A Random Post
    comment_url=ans_list[random.randint(0,len(ans_list)-1)] + '.json?sort=top'  #Grab Random Comment Url and Append .json to end
 
    #Navigate to the Comments
    r = requests.get(comment_url, headers = {'User-agent': 'Chrome'})
    reply= json.loads(r.text)
    
    Children = reply[1]['data']['children']
    
    
    reply_list= []
 
    for post in Children:
        reply_list.append(post["data"]["body"]) #Add Comments to the List
    
    if len(reply_list) == 0:
        return "I have no clue"
        
    #Return a Random Comment
    return reply_list[random.randint(0,len(reply_list)-1)]
 
 
 
#Main Loop, Always ask for a question
while 1:
    input("Ask me anything: ")
    q=q.replace(" ", "+")   #Replace Spaces with + for URL encoding
    print(grab_reply(q))    #Grab and Print the Reply
```

After running the script in my terminal, I get this response:

```
NameError: name 'q' is not defined
```

I have managed to get most of the errors out of my script, but this one is driving me crazy. Help me out, stack overflow.

Comment: Well, where is `q` defined?

Comment: Try: `q = input("Ask me anything: ")`

Comment: Perhaps you meant to assign the input to q?

Comment: `q=q.replace(" ", "+")` where are you expecting the value of `q` to come from, so that `q.replace` can happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input("Ask me anything: ")
```

should be:

```
q = input("Ask me anything: ")
```

Since, you are not assigning the result of the input to any variable. `q` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

probably this will help

```
while True:
    q = input("Ask me anything: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

q is not defined yet. You should defined q before use it.